# Create a horizontal rule in a Word document with Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, xwpf

Is it possible to create a horizontal rule in a Word document using Apache POI? I can't find anything in the documentation that seems relevant. If not, is there some way to insert raw HTML into the document?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
XWPFParagraph p1 = document.createParagraph();
p1.setBorderBottom(Borders.SINGLE);
```

Comment: @Jesse - I don't understand why you added a `<br/>` to the code. That's just a typo, right?

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot Heh. Leo was using `<br />` as linebreaks, then I converted it to code, but inadvertently left it there.